# Larger Image to fit in picturebox

Tags: vb.net, image, scaling

As you'll can see the first image is the size of (1024*768) and it is correctly displayed in the picturebox and in the second case the image size is (1600*900) and it is displayed to half of the picturebox and the remaining is missing .So No I would like to fir that image in the picturebox no matter what the size is and even though it is greater than the size of the picturebox.I need to scale that Image.So how do I do that?And one more thing is that I need to resize the picturebox automatically when the image loads to it just as we see in the lightbox effect..
http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ -------->example.

Any help will be appreciated!

Here is what I am getting.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If it's a winforms app, you can set the `SizeMode` property of the `PictureBox` to `PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom`. Note that this will increase the size of smaller images to fill the frame, so you might want to measure the image first, in order to check if either edge is too long, and then setting `SizeMode` to either `PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom` or `PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal`.

Comment: Yes I have done that and worked but I need to show them with it's actual width and height and at the same time I need to scale the image so that it should fit in that as I have given an example which resembles lightbox with a link and I need to achieve that.

Comment: @volety: in your question you state that you need to scale them. You can't scale and have them in their actual size at the same time.

Comment: I need a simple animation to the picturebox so that it should expand to the size of the Image so how do I do that?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. That is a completely different story. That will probably be a lot easier to achieve in WPF.

Comment: Thanks Fredik for helping me and can you please provide me any link for me and Can I convert my VB.net project to WPF?

Comment: @volety: sorry, never did that so I don't really know any tools for it

Comment: No problem I'm in search of that anyways thanks for making me to think in the other way.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is marked answered, but I wrote this for one of my own apps. Hope it helps somebody..

```
Private Sub ScaleImage(ByVal p As PictureBox, ByRef i As Bitmap)
    If i.Height > p.Height Then
        Dim diff As Integer = i.Height - p.Height
        Dim Resized As Bitmap = New Bitmap(i, New Size(i.Width - diff, i.Height - diff))
        i = Resized
End If
    If i.Width > p.Width Then
        Dim diff As Integer = i.Width - p.Width
        Dim Resized As Bitmap = New Bitmap(i, New Size(i.Width - diff, i.Height - diff))
        i = Resized
End If
```

End Sub

Answer (score 2):

The two Easiest Ways to Fit an Image to Any Size of PictureBox is:

-to set the Image as Background Image 
OR 
-to set it as picturebox image then set sizemode to StretchImage

1.Background Image

-use the **BackgroundImage** property of the PictureBox

```
        picturebox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(New IO.MemoryStream(CType(data, Byte())))
```

-Then Set its BackgroundImageLayout to **stretch** Like This:

```
        picturebox.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
```

2. Image 
   -use the **Image** property of the PictureBox

   ```
   picturebox.Image = Image.FromStream(New IO.MemoryStream(CType(data, Byte())))
   ```

-Then Set its' sizeMode to **StretchImage** Like This:

```
    picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
```

This will make any Picture / Image / Canvas Stroke (converted to Byte Array) fit according to the height and width of the picturebox

Hope This Helps :)